# How are fixture objects written to the Django DB?

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I have a model `A` with an overriden `models.Model.save(…)` method where I instantiate additional objects upon saving an instance of `A`. That is, whenever a new `A` instance is written to the DB or an existing instance gets updated and then saved, a new instance of `B` is created.

When using a fixture to provide the DB with an initial `A` instance, the `A` instance is created as expected but to my surprise after running `loaddata` no `B` instance is present in the DB. This leads me to believe that `A`s `save(…)` method is not called during loading the fixture.

Is this the default behaviour? Are fixture objects not created via the Django ORM system? If so, does this mean that I would have to manually create the `B` instance by specifying it in the fixture?

Comment: A fixture uses `bulk_create` if I recall correctly, which *bypasses* the `.save(..)` function. But there are several functions in the Django ORM that bypass the `.save(..)`, like for example `.update(..)`. Therefore it is in fact *not* a good idea to write required logic into the `.save(..)`.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I guess that `__init__(…)` might be a better place for this kind of logic then.